# "union" or "disjunction" in pure untyped lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, category-theory

In the untyped lambda calculus (with variables, abstraction and application as the only constructors), we have a "pair" construct, given by $(a, b) = \lambda x, x a b$. The projections are then $\pi_i = \lambda x_1 x_2, x_i$ and there is a product function $ \langle f, g \rangle = \lambda x, (f x, g x)$.

TL; DR; Do we also have something like that, but for a copair/disjunction/union?

In the essay [Relating Theories of the lambda-calculus](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/dump/Scott/ScottRelating.pdf), Scott constructs (from page 418) a category $R$, consisting of all idempotent functions $A \circ A = A$. To each of the objects $A$, we can attach a 'set of elements', consisting of all the terms $a$ such that $A a = a$. This category has binary products $A \times B = \langle A \circ \pi_1, B \circ \pi_2 \rangle $, with a set of elements consisting of $x$ that are equal to $(a, b)$ for some element $a$ of $A$ and $b$ of $B$. Note that $A \times B$ is exactly the product function of the two projections onto $A$ and $B$.

My main question here is: does this category have binary coproducts $A \sqcup B$? Is there a type $X$ such that $X x = x$ means "$A x = x$ or $B x = x$" or something like that? Can we construct an idempotent "Bool" which has exactly two elements?

I noticed that we can create injection functions $\iota_1 = \lambda a x_1 x_2, x_1 (A a)$ and $\iota_1 = \lambda b x_1 x_2, x_2 (B b)$ from $A$ and $B$ into a coproduct, and that given functions $f: A \to C$ and $g: B \to C$, we can combine them into a sum function $[f, g] = \lambda x, x f g$. However, when I try to take $A \sqcup B = [\iota_1, \iota_2]$, just like with the binary product, I sadly get something which is not idempotent. Is what I am trying to do just impossible?